How can I bring my non-EU girlfriend to Austria?
My Filipino girlfriend is currently staying in Croatia. She was allowed to enter the EU and work in Croatia based on a work permit in 2023. Due to bad luck (stolen passport and ID card on the day she was applying for a new job) and lengthy bureaucratic processes (to get her documents back, to apply for another work permit), she is now in the situation to have overstayed. So, she didn't get a new work permit. Instead, she received a letter from the police informing her to leave the country.
According to the letter her overstay is 90 days and the consequences, besides leaving the country, is a Schengen entry ban of 6 months.
She's terrified of leaving the country and now I'm evaluating all options to bring her to Austria. I'm an Austrian citizen. There are several options and all of them are fine to us (marriage, education, work in shortage occupation job) but Austrian officials don't easily allow non-EU residents to entry the country. I will do everything to help her to get an education or work but usually language skills are required at minimum. Even for marriage language skill A1 is required.
My questions are:

Is it reasonable to fight the deportation note to buy time? During this time, she could get the certificate for A1 language, and I could prepare all documents and even find work. However, I'm afraid that we need to wait for the outcome of the case before she is free to go? And of course there's the possibility that the court ruling is not in her favor and then deportation takes place anyway.
Is it more reasonable to go back to Philippines and wait until her Schengen ban is lifted? During that time we could prepare everything for her entry to Austria. But it would be far away and it's more difficult to support her there, financially as well as mentally. Also, she's worried about sexual harassment because she was already facing severe issues in her country.
Or is it more reasonable to go to a 3rd country (ie. Serbia) and wait until her Schengen ban is lifted?

Things that we can rule out:

She doesn't have any relatives in Austria or the EU.
She doesn't have any recognized education would get her work easily in Austria - though she finished college with a bachelor degree.


How long is her overstay? Was the letter from the police the first communication she had regarding it? Sounds a bit odd, if so, assuming she reported the theft to the correct authorities. When did you last meet in person?

I've updated some details in the text. Her overstay is 90 days. The letter was the first information she received from the officials. When going to the police (that was on May 22nd) she thought she was going to pick up her work permit. We last met in person from 16th to 22nd of May. As we found out today she unfortunately reported her documents as lost, not as stolen. She reported about her documents to the police in Zagreb.

One note on the logistics of removal or deportation: It always takes time, at the very least to secure permission from the relevant consulate and arrange a flight. So in practice, it means spending some time in detention and you almost always have the option of leaving the country “freely” during this detention (with a police escort to the plane and without access to your passport until after you left). An appeal wouldn't change that. Whether during or after the appeal, it doesn't force you to stay any day longer than necessary in the country.

What are the dates of the initial visa (from, until) and the date the documents were reported as lost?

(EU) Visa was only valid for entry to Croatia March - June 2023. Documents have been reported as stolen in October 2023 in Zagreb. After arrival she received a residence permit which is valid for 9 months and will be extened by the employer.

We've concluded so I want to post an answer here for others to learn from mistakes and what you can do and especially what you cannot do. I’ve worked with an Austrian and a Croatian lawyer and carefully evaluated our options.
The first option, to go to court, may seem the most favorable. In fact, for our problem this option just doesn’t work out. First, the chances to successfully fight deportation are not that high. Second, we also must restore the right of residence for her, which is also questionable. And third, to reach a ruling could easily take more than a year! During this time, she would be trapped in Croatia, without the right to work.
To reach the cancellation of the deportation and to restore the right of residence are important because only then can she apply for a visa to go to Austria (work, education, marriage, etc.). Because of the expected time frame and the little chance of success, we scrapped the idea.
The solution to just move to a 3rd country (ie. Serbia) does also not work, because she also cannot apply for Austrian visa there. Given that she could only apply for a tourist visa in a 3rd country, she doesn’t have the right of residence. This could be different depending on your citizenship, but for Filipinos there is no such country.
So, it came down to the only plausible option to accept the sentence, leave the country (ASAP) and go back to the Philippines. The consequence so far is to pay a fine of 400€ and a Schengen entry ban of 6 months.
However, the Croatian lawyer will re-open the case (if I understood that part correctly) and we try to reduce the ban. Because at the police station she didn’t get a translation of what she’s going to sign! As said, initially she thought this will be the new work permit. She could only do the translation afterwards with a translator app! This is a violation of human rights, and the lawyer just wants to reach the agreement to reduce the ban because she’s leaving voluntarily.


Is it reasonable to fight the deportation note to buy time? During this time, she could get the certificate for A1 language, and I could prepare all documents and even find work. However, I'm afraid that we need to wait for the outcome of the case before she is free to go? And of course there's the possibility that the court ruling is not in her favor and then deportation takes place anyway.

If possible, an appeal is definitely reasonable in those circumstances. That's less critical if you don't intend to live in Croatia later on but immigration infringements of any kind can have a negative impact years down the line so it's always better to do everything you legally can to keep a clean record.
It's difficult to see how such an appeal would curtail her right to leave the country. Unless she is already in detention and as long as she has her passport, your girlfriend will always be free to go. The worse that can happen is that she would be deemed to have abandoned the procedure, that the ban is reinstated, or that the whole time since her permit expired now counts as overstay. And obviously, whatever tolerance Croatia may extend during the procedure does not apply to the rest of the EU (which is why you may have read that she is not “allowed” to leave the country) but that doesn't mean she is barred from, e.g., going back to the Philippines.
I may be wrong about that as I do not know Croatian practices but in general, immediate detention and removal to the Philippines at the end of the procedure also seem unlikely. In the EU countries I know, she would probably get another notification and the opportunity to leave freely (that's much cheaper than a removal and resources are limited). EU law also favors “voluntary” departure at every step of the way, some countries even offer financial incentives (I don't remember all the details off the top but that's what the “Return” directive, directive 2008/115/EC is about). From the perspective of the Croatian authorities, her leaving (especially to the Philippines but also to another country that would take her) is a win, they are not trying to force her to stay in the country any day longer than necessary.

Is it more reasonable to go back to Philippines and wait until her Schengen ban is lifted? During that time we could prepare everything for her entry to Austria. But it would be far away and it's more difficult to support her there, financially as well as mentally. Also, she's worried about sexual harassment because she was already facing severe issues in her country.
Or is it more reasonable to go to a 3rd country (ie. Serbia) and wait until her Schengen ban is lifted?
Or is it more reasonable to go to a 3rd country (ie. Serbia) and wait until her Schengen ban is lifted?

Either of these are reasonable but ultimately the ban may not matter as much as you think. The first order of business is working with a lawyer to find out what she needs to reside in Austria and how to get there. An entry ban is not necessarily a dealbreaker (family life trumps minor immigration infringements), it really depends on Austrian law. In other countries, even irregular stay or entry do not always preclude getting a family residence permits. I do not advocate doing this lightly as it certainly can have very negative consequences but it's important to realize short visits and family reunion are two very different situations legally speaking.
Conversely, if for some reason Austrian law doesn't recognize your relationship or there is some other administrative hiccups, the fact that the ban ended won't be the end of your troubles. While entry in the Schengen area won't be automatically refused, it might remain very difficult for years to come. Consular officers and border guards will have several ways to notice her past overstay and they can still take that into account when determining whether your girlfriend fulfills the requirements for entry.
You should also consider the possibility that she might be refused entry in a third country like Serbia or Turkey (e.g. based on her lack of valid visa or permit for her current stay in Croatia). As a Filipino citizen, the Philippines is the only country she has an iron-clad right to enter. I have no idea how likely that is but the absolute worse case scenario when trying to enter another country is ending up in detention while the local authorities secure permission to return her to the Philippines. Being “bounced” at the land border with Serbia could also prompt Croatian detention and execution of the pending removal order (if that's what you received). There is also the question of what would happen if the appeal in Croatia or procedure in Austria take longer than 90 days (or whatever duration of stay she is granted in that third country).
So while staying in a third country could be a good way to reduce the stress of the current situation, you should primarily focus on securing some stable status in Austria. You might also consider approaching migrant support non-profits in Austria or Croatia, they should be able to advise on the risk of detention and removal and how to avoid it.
If you do marry, one option to consider is moving together to another EU country (or even moving yourself to Croatia). This may seem outlandish and obviously comes with many challenges (finding a job, accommodation, distance from your friends and family, etc.) but I am throwing it out there because that's a way to go around restrictive Austrian regulations. For example, there are no language requirements for the spouse of EU citizens. After some time, you would even be allowed to go back to Austria under these more favorable EU rules (that used to be called the Surinder Singh route in the UK).

There's some promise and hope in there but unfortunately some things are not true. The threat of deportation is severe because once executed it can lead to an additional "lock period" during no Austrian visas can be applied. "family life trumps minor immigration infringements" is not true, or at least not in her case. There must be specific requirements fulfilled to be able to apply for visa. Even though you would marry in another country, she couldn't enter easily my home country. Other points are true, thanks for your help.

@MarkusL There is a bit of a misunderstanding, sorry, this is just a general principle, I didn't mean the overstay didn't matter at all or to be overly optimistic, far from it, that's why it's extremely important to work with a lawyer and like I wrote it depends on Austrian law. I also know that Austria is particularly restrictive and as far as I understand you are not married (yet) so it definitely wouldn't help you right now. But you have to rely on that down the line otherwise it will be extremely difficult for your girlfriend to come back even after the ban is lifted.

Incidentally, going around restrictive spouse visa requirement is the reason why people use the Surinder Singh route at the end, which is why I mentioned it.

Can you elaborate on it will be extremely difficult to come back? I know that we would need to find a specific reason for her to enter again (work permit or education permit or marriage allowance) but once the ban is lifted the Austrian lawyer confirmed that it's basically possible to apply for visa again. Or are there any other obstacle which we need to consider?

@MarkusL Yes, it's possible to apply, the refusal is not automatic anymore but even fulfilling the requirements does not mean you are entitled to a visa. Especially for a short-stay or education visa, you still to overcome the presumption that you may abuse the visa and are just using it as a pretext to enter the country, marry, and settle without applying for the right visa. By contrast, this may not matter for a work visa but the requirements for those are difficult to meet in the first place.

Obviously, this shouldn't matter for a family reunion visa where settling in the country is very much the purpose, which is part of what I meant when I said you should focus on that more than anything.

Incidentally, there are countries (e.g. France) where it is in fact possible to apply for a long-stay visa while there is an alert in the SIS and that alert is not in and of itself enough to refuse the visa, the consular officer must consider the reasons behind the alert and balance them with the other facts in the application (including the right to family life). The common thread between these different scenarios is that when it comes to long-stay visa, bans do not work like an on/off switch, they are just one factor that is weighed with all the other factors of the application.
